# write with symbol name for stock to database

Tags: python, pandas

How would I also write the symbol to the database after a resample in pandas?

```
dfPrice = df2.set_index('new_date').groupby(['symbol'])['price'].resample('1Min').ohlc()

    sql.to_sql(dfPrice,
               name=table_name + '_1Min',
               con=cnx,
               index=False,    # don't use CSV file index
               index_label='id',  # a unique column from DataFrame as index
               if_exists='append')
```

outputing the head() will give

```
symbol new_date
203    2019-01-08 08:40:00  8.58  8.58  8.58   8.58
       2019-01-08 08:41:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
       2019-01-08 08:42:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

But writing to DB will not give the symbol column to the database

Answer (score 0):

you may want to do `sql.to_sql(dfPrice.reset_index()...` since `symbol` is the index of `dfPrice` and it may not get exported by `sql`. Or change the flag `index=True` and `index_label`?

Comment: symbol is not the index new_date is

Comment: Once you do `groupby(['symbol'])`, `symbol` is the index.